# R survift() - separate plots for each level of IV

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis

I'm very new to R and to survival analyses. I'm trying to plot survival curves for each level of a categorical IV. Importantly, I want them plotted on *separate* plots. Is there an easy way to do this? An obvious solution is to just create separate data frames for the categories, however, that seems rather cumbersome.

my code:

```
figure_site <- survfit(survObject~site, data = uis_data) 
plot(figure_site)
```

site has 2 levels (0, 1) and I want two plots - one for site==0 and site==1.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified - The code I have there plots 2 curves on the *same* plot. I'm chasing separate plots.

Comment: I can't test this but, what happens if you assign the plot to a variable? You could do: `p<-plot(figure_site)`, then: `p[[1]]` and `p[[2]]` to access each. Again can't test this, just a hunch.

Comment: No [MCVE] so I'm not making up one. It should be fairly easy, once there is data.